# NSEvent.keyCode to unicode character in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, events

I'm trying to develop a macOS app, and I need to listen to keypress events.

I'm able to do this using the following class:

```
import Cocoa

class EditorWindow: NSWindow {
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.keyDown(with: event)
        Swift.print("Caught a key down: \(event.keyCode)!")
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the key code of each letters, such as `A = 0` and `S = 1`.

But, in this context, the key code doesn't seem to fit well with Unicode scalars, so I'm unable to convert these key values to `Character`.

Is there any way to convert the `UInt16` output of the `NSEvent.keyCode` output to a `Character` or a `String`?

Comment: What about using the `characters` property of `NSEvent`?

Comment: @rmaddy Could you tell me more about this property? Like how to use it?

Comment: I know nothing about it. I just saw it in the documentation for `NSEvent`. Add it to your `print` statement and see what you get.

Comment: Or try the documentation [Key Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventObjectsTypes/EventObjectsTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH4-SW5) and [event.characters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534183-characters).

Comment: @Willeke Thank you, it works. You can write the answer, so I can approve it 

Comment: Don't thank me, thank @rmaddy.

Comment: @Willeke You're right

Comment: Then @rmaddy you can right your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSEvent` has a property named `characters`:

> var characters: String?
>
> The characters associated with a key-up or key-down event.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> var characters: String? { get }
>
> **Discussion**
>
> These characters are derived from a keyboard mapping that associates various key combinations with Unicode characters. This property is only valid for key-up and key-down events. It raises an NSInternalInconsistencyException if accessed on any other kind of event object.
>
> This property is set to an empty string for dead keys, such as Option-e. However, for a key combination such as Option-Shift-e this property is set to the standard accent ("´").
>
> For a list of constants corresponding to commonly-used Unicode characters, see NSText.

Comment: Note that there is also a charactersIgnoringModifiers() function that ignores all modifiers (command, control, etc.) except for the shift key. it may not have much effect but it is different and could matter in some cases.